Hybrid 2d animation/live action film about a kid who goes to Mars and his sister has to rescue him
This was a 1980s or 1990s 2d/live-action hybrid film about 2d kid go to mars on a van get captured by aliens and his sister had to go save her brother on mars via printer and free her brother from jail in mars

Was that Aliens Stole My Punctuation?

FWIW this is a repost of this (unanswered) Reddit post, with important bits of the plot left out, and some heavy formatting to apply if said bits are to be copied here.

"2d" move - does that mean that everything takes place in a single plane?
